# When installing PHP development tools for Eclipse, what's the difference between PDT and PDT SDK?

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I'm about to install PDT, and there are 2 options:

```
PHP development tools (PDT)
PHP development tools (PDT) SDK Feature
```

What's the difference?

Comment: In Kepler, the <SDK Feature> option is no longer there.

Comment: In Eclipse version 2018-09, I see two options: `PHP Development Tools` and `PHP Development Tools (SDK)`.